# I have 64 bit OS (Win 7) but when I check the sizeof(pointer) it says 4 byte . Should it not be 8 byte for 64 bit OS

Tags: c++

I have read many posts that for a 16 bit system the `sizeof(ptr)` should be 2 byte , for a 32 bit system `sizeof(ptr) = 4 byte` and for a 64 bit system  `sizeof(ptr) = 8` byte  and it makes sense also but on my machine which has a 64 bit OS (4 GB RAM)  its says the `sizeof(ptr) = 4 byte` . Can someone explains it to me. Thanks

Comment: Did you install a 32-bit compiler?

Comment: Install a 64 bits Linux on your machine (e.g. Debian/AMD64) and you'll get 8 byte pointers.

Comment: Your information is correct about the different sizes of pointer for different OS bits, but have you checked that if the interface in which you are running the program is 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: Indeed. Just because your computer is 64bit, doesn't mean your compiler is. You typically have to tell it to explicitly compile 64bit binaries. Most 64bit operating systems have a method of masking to the 32bit code that they're running on a 64bit address space.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This has (almost) nothing to do with OS and everything with the compiler and the flags passed to the compiler. If switching the OS "fixes" the problem, it only does so coincidentally because the default compiler coming with that OS has different defaults.

Comment: No its a 64-bit compiler. That's why I am also confused.

Comment: @FarhanGDon Well, what compiler exactly and how do you invoke it?

Comment: Your `sizeof(ptr)` doesn't have a known value until runtime, so despite being a 64-bit compiler, it must have compiled a 32-bit binary.

Comment: Compiling for a 32-bit target means you get a 4 byte pointer, even on a 64-bit OS. Compile for a 64-bit target instead.

Comment: @delnan its visual studio 64-bit . and Thanks for Your replies. I think there is some issue with compiler rest I got the correct idea. Thanks All.

Comment: @OllieFord What? `sizeof(x)` is always a compile time constant (discounting C99 VLAs). Pointer size, as many other crucial parameters, is decided at compile time.

Comment: Further, the reason this is the case is straightforward to see - we use 64-bit addressing to have (that is, be able to address) more memory locations, since there are more combinations of address number if you like in 64 bits than 32. 64 bits = 8 Bytes, since a pointer is just an address of what is pointed to, the size of the pointer is equal to the size of the address.

Comment: @delnan - I have no idea why I said that. !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel CPUs have the ability to execute 16, 32 and 64-bit binaries. The question is: which were you testing?

Both Windows and Linux are available in 32 and 64-bit versions. The difference is that 32-bit cannot execute 64-bit binaries, whereas 64-bit can.

If (and only if) you have a 64-bit OS and a 64-bit-capable development system and you write a program and explicitly tell it to generate a 64-bit program then when you run it you will see 8 byte pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in the comments you're using Visual Studio.  To setup this compiler to build 64bit solutions the following will work for Visual Studio 2010, 2012, and 2013.  The steps below were taken from the [Microsoft MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

1. Right click on your solution in the solution explorer.
2. Choose properties.
3. Click the <kbd>Configuration Manager...</kbd> in the upper right corner.
4. Click the drop down arrow under `Active solution configuration`
5. Choose `New` and enter a name for this configuration.  i.e. Debug64 or Release64
6. Click the drop down arrow under `Copy settings from` and Choose Win32. Copying from Win32 will automatically update multiple settings to 64bit.
7. Click <kbd>Ok</kbd>.
8. Under `Active solution platform` choose `New`
9. Under the platform should be an option for x64.  Select this and click <kbd>Ok</kbd>.
10. Click <kbd>Close</kbd>.

You should now be building for the x64 platform and your pointers will be size 8.

To change back to 32bit, open the configuration manager again and choose the correct `Configuration` and `Platform`.